# Batch script output to website

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

I have a batch script set up on my DC server to monitor my internet connection and other things but I'd like it to be hosted online on my site instead.

Does anyone know how to output the results to a log file hosted on a server?

Locally this works perfectly:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
echo %date% >> Google-log.txt
echo %time% >> Google-log.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 4 >> Google-log.txt
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

However I would like it to be on my website so I can see the results without having to log into the server to check the logs.

Something like this perhaps?

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
echo %date% >> 173.252.120.6\Google-log.txt
echo %time% >> 173.252.120.6\Google-log.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 4 >> 173.252.120.6\Google-log.txt
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

But then I'm not sure how to authorise the user to edit the files? Is it possible to SSH into a server through a batch script?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: assuming it's all a windows network, `>> \\servername\sharename\google-log.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately its an external server, though I may be able to get a VPN set up so that it is on the same network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an SSH access, you can most probably use an SFTP too. So use any command-line SFTP client to upload the output.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/):

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
echo %date% > Google-log.txt
echo %time% >> Google-log.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 4 >> Google-log.txt

winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@173.252.120.6/" ^
    "put -append Google-log.txt" ^
    "exit"

GOTO LOOPSTART
```

Note how the output file is overwritten in each loop (`>` instead of `>>` after the first `echo`) and appended to the remote file (the `-append` switch), not to re-upload the whole log each time.

For details see the [guide to automating SFTP/FTP transfers with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP access to the web server, you can easily configure an ftp script. The ftp client included with windows allows you to supply a -s flag to specify a script file:
`ftp -s:myscript.txt`

myscript.txt (untested):

> open 173.252.120.6
>
> cd logs
>
> put Google-log.txt
>
> quit

You can find more info by starting the ftp client in a command prompt window and typing `help`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of FTP. I'll have a look into doing this through batch scripts to loop the upload with the ping tests. Cheers jason :-)